# $null for ValueFromPipeline

Tags: powershell

I've recently been writing a function, which required to accept parameters through the pipeline and I see very strange behaviour of it. I have following code:

```
Function Write-A
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$InputObject
    )
    Write-Host $InputObject
}

1,2,3 | Write-A 
1,2,3 | % { Write-Host $_ }
```

These is the output of the script:

```
3
1
2
3
```

Why Write-A function writes only last element?

Comment: I found a way to fix my issue. It turned out that Write-Host... was a part of end block, so when I wrapped it in process {} things started to work correct. But I still don't get it, why end block didn't gave me conversion from array to string error?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing only the last element in the array to your function.  You need to loop over each item like this:

```
1,2,3 | % { Write-A $_ }
```

alternatively, you could have your function take an array like so:

```
Function Write-A
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [array]$InputObject
    )
    $InputObject | % { Write-Host $_ }
}

Write-A 1,2,3
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I don't understand, why PowerShell thinks that I'm passing the last element of the pipeline to the function input

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you've figured out that you need a Process block if you're going to use the pipeline.

As far as why it's not giving you an error, remember that the pipeline "unrolls" collections and arrays into a stream of individual objects.  Since you're passing that array through the pipeline, your function is seeing the numbers one at a time, converting each one to [string] as it passes through the pipeline.

Try passing it as an argument so it doesn't get unrolled by the pipeline and see what happens:

```
 Function Write-A
{
   [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string]$InputObject
  )
    Write-Host $InputObject
}


Write-A 1,2,3
```

Comment: I've tried this and got an error that array can't be converted to string. Also I'm trying to avoid have a full array in memory, that's the main reason why I need pipeline based implementation.